# Diazo theming in Plone 4.3 is unresponsive

Tags: plone, theming, diazo

The theming tab in Plone 4.3 on my server is unresponsive. The *New theme* and *Upload zip file* buttons both do nothing when clicked and if i press the *Save* button at the bottom I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 60, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module plone.app.theming.browser.controlpanel, line 50, in __call__
Module plone.app.theming.browser.controlpanel, line 166, in update
Module plone.app.controlpanel.skins, line 147, in set_use_popups
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setEnabled'
```

The only thing on the theming control panel that works is activating the theme and also the help button. When clicking on themes or advanced it brings me to the front page of Plone with `#fieldsetlegend-advanced` in the URL.

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: Any chance this is an updated site and that you haven't run the migration?